# Ionic 2 : Use ng2-translate in a ts file

Tags: javascript, angular, translation, ionic2, ng2-translate

I want to use a translation in an object to use the toast on Ionic 2. But I don't understand how to use ng2-translate in a .ts file...
Somenone can show me an example ?

I want to have a translation in a title in my menu. I try like this but it doesn't work :

```
constructor(public platform: Platform, public menu: MenuController, public translate : TranslateService) {
this.initializeApp();

translate.setDefaultLang('fr');
translate.use('fr');
let testTrad : string = 'Accueil';

translate.get('TEST').subscribe(res => {testTrad = res; console.log(testTrad)});
console.log(testTrad);

// Remplissage du tableau des pages.
this.pages= [
  {title: testTrad ,                  component: TabsPage},
  {title: 'Mon compte',               component: MyAccountPage},
  {title: 'Changer de mot de passe' , component: ChangePasswordPage},
  {title: 'Documents' ,               component: DocumentsPage}
]
```

It must be display "test" on my menu, but it continue to display "Accueil".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that's correct,

```
translate.get('TEST').subscribe(res => {testTrad = res; console.log(testTrad)});
console.log(testTrad);

// Remplissage du tableau des pages.
this.pages= [
  {title: testTrad ,                  component: TabsPage},
  {title: 'Mon compte',               component: MyAccountPage},
  {title: 'Changer de mot de passe' , component: ChangePasswordPage},
  {title: 'Documents' ,               component: DocumentsPage}
]
```

`.subscribe` is async, so the values assigned *within* the `subscribe`, are not yet accessible

Try

```
translate.get('TEST').subscribe(res => {
    testTrad = res; 
    console.log(testTrad);
    this.pages= [
       {title: testTrad ,                  component: TabsPage},
       {title: 'Mon compte',               component: MyAccountPage},
       {title: 'Changer de mot de passe' , component: ChangePasswordPage},
       {title: 'Documents' ,               component: DocumentsPage}
    ]
});
console.log(testTrad);
```

Or, if you don't want to wait for the async the finish you could try

```
this.pages= [
  {title: 'Mon compte',               component: MyAccountPage},
  {title: 'Changer de mot de passe' , component: ChangePasswordPage},
  {title: 'Documents' ,               component: DocumentsPage}
]
translate.get('TEST').subscribe(res => {
   testTrad = res;
   this.pages.push({title: testTrad, component: TabsPage});
 });
```

Comment: It work but I have another problem ...
I can' use the traduction because I receive an async response. I want to insert my trad in a variable and use it directly. I don't know if you see what I mean ?

Comment: No I'm not sure what you mean. Are you talking about the `translate.get().subscribe()`?

Comment: Yes. This do an asynchrone request.

" let testTrad : string;
translate.get('TEST').subscribe(res => {testTrad = res;});
console.log(testTrad); "

In this part of code my console.log doesn't display anything because I receive my "res" to late.

Comment: Ok for `async` methods, you cannot use the variable outside of it. What you can do is create a seperate function `setVariable` where you can do anything you like with your returned response. 

I don't understand what your issue is and what you're trying to create so can't provide you with code

Comment: I have update my question to show you what I want to do. :)

Comment: But just saying, you should've made it into another question, just because someone else could have made the same issue you had before and now he wouln't be able to find it anymore :)